# Xamarin Media Plug in crashing for selecting image from photo library

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using [Media Plugin for Xamarin and Windows](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) in Xamarin Forms app to take picture from Camera and select one from photo library. Camera functionality works fine but selecting a picture from photo library crashing the app. The exception is -
Unable to get metadata: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Here is code

```
  if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
  {
      DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", ":( Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
      return;
  }
  var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

  if (file == null)
     return;

  showImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
  {
      var stream = file.GetStream();
      file.Dispose();
      return stream;
  });
```

Is there a setting for metadata I need to do?

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/545

Comment: Found a fix. Need to add Photo Library Usage Description